# Creating a parameter from a player object

Tags: c#

This might seem like a stupid question but I am having trouble passing a parameter into a constructor in one of my classes. The object I have created is a player object and I am trying to get its position in my enemy class. The reason why I am trying to do this is because I want my enemies to follow the player around the screen. I am using c# in psm to create this program. Any assistance is greatly needed.

This is my enemy class.

```
public class SmartEnemy:Enemy
{

  private Player player;

    private Vector3 vel, pos;
    private static Random gen= new Random();



    public SmartEnemy (GraphicsContext g, Texture2D t, Vector3 p, float pwr, Player pop) : base(g,t,p,pwr)
    {
        pos = p; 
        player = pop;
        vel = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        sprite.Rotation = 0;
        sprite.Center.X = 0.5f;
        sprite.Center.Y = 0.5f;
    }


public override void Update()
{

    Vector3 playerPos= player.Pos;
    double angle=Math.Atan2(playerPos.Y-sprite.Position.Y,playerPos.X- sprite.Position.X);
    Vector3 vel=new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(angle),(float)Math.Sin(angle),0);
    sprite.Position+=vel;

}
public override void Render()
{
sprite.Render();    
}

}
```

//
}
This is my code in my Appmain that creates an enemy.

```
pieces.Add (new SmartEnemy(graphics, eTex, new Vector3(gen.Next (200,900), gen.Next (200,900),0),.5f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SmartEnemy constructor expects a Player object, yet you're not supplying one in your code:

```
SmartEnemy(graphics, eTex, new Vector3(gen.Next (200,900), gen.Next (200,900),0),.5f));
```

Create a player object and send in:

```
Player p1 = new Player();
pieces.Add( new SmartEnemy(graphics, eTex, new Vector3(gen.Next (200,900), gen.Next (200,900),0),.5f, p1) );
```